# jquery - how to query for options passed with event

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I'm listening for an event and when fired, I want to check some of the associated options.

This is what I have:

```
// event firing
$.mobile.changePage(href, {fromHashChange: false});

// listening
$(..target..).bind('changePage', function(event, data) {
   console.log(data)
   });
```

The console returns the options set in the function call. I'm just not getting anywhere trying to query for the individual options...

Question: how can I query for `fromHashChange`?

**EDIT**
This is the working solution:

`console.log(data.object.fromHashChange);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do -

```
var x = data.fromHashChange;
```

or

```
var x = data['fromHashChange'];
```

Comment: I get "undefined"...  I think data is an object, that contains an object called "options"?, because console.log(data) returns Object { toPage=[1], options={...}} and fromHashChange is inside "options"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(..target..).bind('changePage', function(event, data) {
   console.log(data.fromHashChange);
   //or
   // console.log(data['fromHashChange']);
});
```